# C# Resizing Bitmap without changing the Pixelformat

Tags: c#, bitmap, emgucv

I have a bitmap in BGR format and resolution 1920*1200 and want to scale it without changing the pixelformat.

```
private Bitmap rescale(Size size, Bitmap origin)
{
    Bitmap scaled = new Bitmap(origin, size);
    return scaled;
}
```

the problem is, that scaled turns out to be a RGBA bitmap(all alphas at 255), which is not only useless to me, but also troubles me as later I am doing a AbsDiff (from EMGU) on different images and then, the alpha value always turns out zero..
Is there a way to not change the pixelformat when scaling or to do AbsDiff without the alpha-values? Because like this, when I load the image later, it is invisible..

Comment: There should be a constructor overload that takes a PixelFormat argument. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z132tat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You could create the target with the desired pixelformat and the desired size and then use Graphic.DrawImage to copy the scaled version into the target.

Comment: I'd recommend using the overload that virusrocks gave in his answer.  It will do it automatically (at least that's what MSDN claims).  To do it manually you would create a Graphics object from the new bitmap and use one of it's DrawImage overloads to paint the original image on to the new one.

Comment: what virusrocks used in his answer was exactly what I tried, and it didn't work.. I trying to use a Graphics object now..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
   Bitmap scaled = new Bitmap(origin, size);
```

There are a lot of implicit assumptions built into that constructor call.  You'll get:

- A bitmap with the 32bppPArgb pixel format.  Meant to help the programmer fall into the pit of success, it is the most optimal pixel format on modern PCs.  Compatible with the pixel format of the video adapter frame buffer, it can be blitted without any conversion.  It is *ten* times faster than all the other ones.
- The resolution is set to the video adapter DPI.  This is usually a bit less optimal although it is pretty hard to argue that it should use the resolution of the source image after rescaling it.  You might want to modify that.
- A transparent background.  That matters if the source bitmap has transparency or has pixels with the alpha channel set to a value < 255.  Usually fine, if the source bitmap was transparent then the new one will be as well.  Not so fine with alpha, rescaling the bitmap is pretty likely to affect that negatively.  YMMV.
- Bilinear interpolation of the source image.  That is fairly modest, you might favor InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic for a better result, especially when you shrink it by more than 50%.  Or NearestNeighbor if speed is your concern or the source image is very small and you enlarge it with the intention to keep the pixels visible as-is.

Clearly you are unhappy, the first bullet is the source of your complaint.  Writing it out with all details tweakable:

```
    public static Bitmap RescaleImage(Image source, Size size) {
        // 1st bullet, pixel format
        var bmp = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, source.PixelFormat);
        // 2nd bullet, resolution
        bmp.SetResolution(source.HorizontalResolution, source.VerticalResolution);
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
            // 3rd bullet, background
            gr.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            // 4th bullet, interpolation
            gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gr.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height));
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

  -

Answer (score 5):

The (admittedly sort of ugly) way I would do this is to create a new Bitmap with the original Pixelformat and the new Size and draw the original bitmap onto it (untested):

```
private Bitmap rescale(Size size, Bitmap origin)
{
    Bitmap rescaled = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, origin.PixelFormat);
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rescaled))
    {
         g.DrawImage(origin, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
    }
    return rescaled;
}
```

Comment: this is not ugly at all.

Comment: this was fantastic! Just solved a big problem I was having! Copy, paste, call, done!

Comment: Just for the compliment, this will fail if the PixelFormat is indexed, as in B/W images.

Answer (score -3):

This seems to be what you need:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/552141/Csharp-Image-resize-convert-and-save

and

> [`Bitmap(Image, Size)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wh0045z.aspx)

```
public Bitmap(
    Image original,
    Size newSize
)
```

This is a constructor that takes a new size. The image is automatically resized to that size.